# Subfigures in a figure, how to label?

Tags: technical-writing, formatting, academic-writing, scientific-publishing

[image: Figure with two sub-figures, (i) and (ii)]

So if I later refer to figure 2 (i) or figure 2 (ii) would it be better for the figure to be labelled as is Figure 2: Figure (i) shows cycle C? or

Figure 2:  (i) shows cycle C or

Figure 2:  Subfigure (i) shows cycle C

I'm not sure if this is the right forum but I didn't see a scientific writing forum.

Comment: This is the correct SE site.  Since the merger with the, now defunct, Technical Communications site - https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1473/29719

Answer (score 1):

Within the figure description itself, just use (i), (ii), (iii), etc.or (A), (B), (C), (D) to save space.

In the text of your paper, refer to Figure 2(i), Figure 2(ii), or Figure 2(A), Figure 2(B).

As in (for figure description):

> Figure 2: (A) reflex, (B) recoil

As in (for body text):

> In Figure 2(A) we see the reflex action of the potential, while Figure 2(B) shows the subsequent recoil action.

Answer (score 0):

Using the simple expression:

> Figure 2(i) shows cycle C

is succinct and conveys the required meaning.

It is usually preferable to keep such references short and you will see many such examples in the literature.
The extraneous words used in your other suggestions add nothing to your intentions.